# How to invert a triangle (make its base its top and its top its base)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

Here is the triangle I want to invert:

```
\newcommand{\arrowL}{
    \tikz \draw[latex-] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}
\newcommand{\arrowR}{
    \tikz \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(2,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
\draw (2,0)--(2,2) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
\draw (0,0)--(2,2) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
\node[left] at (0,0) {$v_2$};
 \node[above] at (2,2) {$v_1$};
 \node[below] at (2,0) {$v_3$};
\node[above] at (1,1) {$a$};
 \node[above] at (2.2,1) {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am using document class book, could anyone help me in inverting this triangle please?

Comment: Have you tried to invert all the coordinates? Like turning `(2.2, 1)` into `(2.2,-1)`?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Besides @tobiasBora's suggestion, you could try `x=-1, y=-1` (or perhaps just one of those, depeding on what exactly that you want.

Comment: There is also the `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]` option to rotate a drawing without rotating the text

Comment: @Brain, this is your third question in a row asking for *minimal* changes to the diagrams you are trying to draw... I suggest you take a deep breath and try to *understand* what the code is doing, you will save a lot of time that way. Also, please read through the first tutorial in Ti*k*Z manual: https://tikz.dev/tutorial

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will do so next times.@Rmano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to change the labels for the points or the segments.You rotate what you want ...

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tkzSetUpLine[line width=.4pt,color=teal]
\tikzset{arrow/.style={
         decoration={markings,
         mark= at position .5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}}}}  
\begin{document}
   
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-135]
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){v_1}
   \tkzDefPoint(2,0){v_2}
   \tkzDefTriangle[isosceles right](v_1,v_2) \tkzGetPoint{v_3}
 \end{scope}
 \tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](v_3,v_2 v_1,v_3 v_1,v_2)
 \tkzLabelPoints(v_1,v_2,v_3)
 \tkzLabelSegment(v_1,v_3){$b$}
 \tkzLabelSegment(v_2,v_1){$a$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=135]
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){v_1}
   \tkzDefPoint(2,0){v_2}
   \tkzDefTriangle[isosceles right](v_2,v_1) \tkzGetPoint{v_3}
 \end{scope}
 \tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](v_3,v_2 v_1,v_3 v_1,v_2)
 \tkzLabelPoints(v_1,v_2,v_3)
 \tkzLabelSegment[swap](v_1,v_3){$b$}
 \tkzLabelSegment[swap](v_2,v_1){$a$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The label v_2 is on the line...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I know ... but it's easy to change a lot of things but some notions of TikZ or tkz-euclide are necessary. Here `tkzLabelPoints[below left](v_2)`for example and `\tkzLabelPoints(v_1,v_3)`. It's possible to use `\tkzAutoLabelPoints`

Answer (score 2):

To my opinion is the simplest way to draw image from scratch. Just determine desired coordinates and draw lines between them. In this I would use of your commands use `decorations.markings` library and define style for connewction lines as is done in MWE below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Triangle[angle=60:2pt 3]}}},
              postaction={decorate},
              line cap=round},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\draw[->-]  
    (0, 0) node[above] {$v_1$} to["$a$"] (2, 0) node[above] {$v_2$};
\draw[->-]
    (2, 0) to["$b$"] (2,-2) node[below] {$v_3$};
\draw[->-]
    (2,-2) to["$c$"] (0, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If direction of arrows is not as you wish to be, than accordingly interchange their coordinates.